# JS Twitter Widget Always Creates New Line Break, Need On Same Line

Tags: javascript, twitter, widget

I need the following JS Twitter widget to appear on the same line as the "TEST MESSAGE" texts, however it always creates a line break and this code appears as three lines.

```
TEST MESSAGE<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 10,
  interval: 30000,
  width: 370,
  height: 500,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#333333',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#e8e8e8',
      color: '#000000',
      links: '#005eff'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().setUser('ControllerShop').start();
</script>TEST MESSAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter widget renders as a `<div>`, which is a block element and so behaves this way by default (just like any other block element like `<p>` or `<blockquote>`). To make it display inline with the text try:

```
.twtr-widget {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see it in action [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R26d3/) (make sure the "Result" pane is wide enough to accommodate everything).

It's not really clear why you'd want to do this so I'm curious about your larger use case, but this does the job anyway.

Comment: Hello, I added the code and now the widget simply doesn't appear at all! lol. But, the reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to display a facebook widget directly to the right of it.

Comment: Where did you add the code? If you want to display another block element to the right of it then you should use `float: right;` or `float: left;` on one or the other. Just to clarify, this is CSS, not JavaScript. It should go in your stylesheet.

Comment: Is there a way to do it within the widget or in the section of code, without accessing the style sheet and everything? I'm using Volusion e-commerce so this code just goes into an article that is automatically put in the website.

Comment: Well you could just add a `<style>` block before it in your article's HTML.

Comment: this would look like: <style float:left> ...code... </style>?

Comment: No. Perhaps you should back up and start with a CSS tutorial. There are many out there. Here's a couple links to get you started: [westciv.com](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/academy/hands_on_tutorial/01.introduction.html), [quackit.com](http://www.quackit.com/css/tutorial/css_introduction.cfm), [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html)